# Липсинг или Липсинк?

Tags: транслитерация

Is there any explanation why a lot of sites use "липсинг" word instead of "липсинк"? Obviously it's russian version of the "lip-sync" word and should be written as "липсинк". Sure thing I know it's not "official" russian word but I'm still wondering.

P.S: http://www.trpub.ru/perevod-video/lipsing/ even this site that provides translation services uses "липсинг" version.

Comment: In this article from "ТВ Культура", popular and respected Russian TV channel, they use _липсинк_: http://tvkultura.ru/article/show/article_id/27857/; but then again, in this article about dubbing from Wikipedia, they use _липсинг_: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Липсинк in ТВ Культура's article refers to the name of the show (спектакль "Липсинк"), so, as a proper name, it does not need to have correct speling. Though there is one mentioning of a term: '"Липсинк" – это кинематографический термин', though as it is quoted it's not clear if they use russian term or just explain what's the meaning of the show name is.

Comment: "lip-sing" does make some sense :)

Comment: http://www.trpub.ru/perevod-video/lipsing/ - As you can see, they also know that it is "synch", not "sing" and nevertheless they write: "Липсинг (от англ. «lips» — губы и «synch» — синхронизация) – полная синхронизация звукового и визуального ряда в фильмах."

Comment: I'd say someone made blint idiot translation once (a la "ring the bell" -> "рынду бей") and the rest just blindly followed suit. I, personally, didn't knew about people using "липсинГ" until today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though correct transliteration of lyp-sync is липсин**К**, липсин**Г** is often used instead, because the word is not listed in dictionaries, and as such, Russian speakers use their language feeling to decide which writing form suites best in this case. Note that most Russian speakers do not know English, so they do not use English rules here.

So, from a perspective of Russian-speaker, a word that sounds like [липсинк] can be written in two ways: липсинк and липсинг (both writings are pronounced the same way - [липсинк], this process is known as [devoicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final-obstruent_devoicing#Russian)). Russian speaker knows that many borrowed words (they may or may not be aware of English origin of those words) have 'инг' at the end: фактчекинг, лизинг, конвертинг, спарринг, допинг, шопинг, тюнинг, кастинг, тренинг and so on and so forth. Since [липсинк] obviously goes to borrowed category, it seems that 'инг' ending is 'more correct' than 'инк' ending. This version is also backed by the fact that writing 'инк' in this position instead of 'инг' is a common spelling error (since both endings are pronounced the same way).

<sub>And in fact 'инк' ending is not common to other Russian words as well. Almost all nouns that have such ending are limited by: цинк, сцинк (lizard), инк (one of Inca people). Other words are proper and family names like Метерлинк, Хиддинк, Пинк Флойд. Non-listed in dictionaries, but known are линк (пруфлинк, гиперлинк), дринк (софт-дринк, лонг-дринк). So we have here only 10 nouns (plus 20 family names), while there are [over 400](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?s=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3]&FindNouns=ON&a=133) words ending with -инг.</sub>

Such transformation, based on common native speakers impression what is 'correct' and what is 'incorrect' resulted in modification of borrowed or existing Russian words with spelling similar to common spelling errors:

- Initially **Фляшка** - later replaced with **фляжка** (borrowed from Polish flasza, looks like шк/жк misspelling)
- **Пошта** - **почта** (borrowed from Polish росztа, looks like шт/чт misspelling)
- **Машта** - **мачта** (borrowed from Dutch mast, looks like шт/чт misspelling)

Though липсин**г** may look more correct for a Russian eye (non-aware of English grammar and phonetics), the fact that most dictionaries do not contain this word, and existence of дринк and линк leaves a chance that consistent usage of липсинк will overcome incorrect transliteration.

Comment: This would be correct if it was "lipsing", but the English word is "lip-sync"

Comment: @Alissa Yes, correct transliteration is липсинк, but this is very uncommon to have English borrowing ending with -инк: дринк, софт-дринк, линк, пруфлинк, пинк (short for Пинк Флойд) and that's all. Most of these borrowings are slangish, while 'инг' borrowings are plenty and are listed in dictionaries. And in fact even Russian words ending with 'инк' are very rare (цинк, сцинк), other are proper or family names like Метерлинк or Хиддинк.

Comment: Sorry, previous version of your answer was confusing. I read it as "-ing words end with инг, hence this one should too". After a thought I'd agree with you. Though if I was translating an article with this word, I'd probably used липсинк rather than липсинг.

Comment: @Artemix, just to draw your attention, the words you've used to back the _-инг_-form originally end in _-ing_: shopp_ing_, cast_ing_, etc. Whereas lip-syn_c_ is short for lip synchronization, it follows a different word-building pattern. More about the phenomenon: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lip_sync

Comment: @Artemix, also, the person performing lip-sync is called a _lip-syncer_, or a _lip-syncher_, not a 'lip-singer.' This activity includes but isn't limited to singing.

Comment: I know that sync is not sing, but for average Russian speaker (most of them do not speak English) it does not matter what was the English word used in the expression. As another example, english-borrowed word glamour (properly written in Russian as гл*а*ма, with stress on first А) looks like French fashion word and, as such is pronounced "глам*у*р", with stress on у, because it looks like абажур, гарнитур, бонжур, Помпадур, трубадур, etc. So, as a bottom line, borrowed word is written as it is heard by Russian ear, using the most correct-looking way of writing (-инк is typical spelling error).

Comment: "Often"? In google search "синк" outnumbers "синг" by two times and it offers "did you mean липсинк" prompt as well. As a personal anecdote, today is the first day I EVER found out that there's people who write this with "г".

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov I listened a lecture of a linguist that used Google and Yandex for calculating statistics of word usages. He told that when numbers are exceeding several hundreds the results for both searching engines are incorrect (this is "estimated" value, not real one). So, I tried to click "next" for both searches and asked google not to omit similar results. Липсинк results ended at page 65, липсинг ended on page 63. With 10 links per page this gives 650 vs 630 - almost 50.7% vs 49.3%.